# Getting marginal effects after a panel oprobit regression in Stata (using gllamm package)

Tags: stata, panel-data, marginal-distribution, order-statistics, gllamm

I am trying to estimate the number of companies entering certain markets using panel data.  To do so, I ran an ordered probit regression in `Stata` using the `gllamm` package.  The number of companies goes from 0 to 5.  The command is as follows (where `id` = a fixed market):

`gllamm NCompanies independent_variables, i(id) link(oprobit)`

The outcome, if I understood it correctly, gives the cut points of a latent variable and the impact each independent variable has on the latent variable.  So far so good to me, I ran into troubles when I tried to estimate the marginal effects using the commands `mfx` or `margins`.  When I type

`mfx, dydx`

I get exactly the same results as displayed by the `gllamm` (?!) minus the cut points.  So, I don´t know if the `gllamm` was already showing the marginal effects or if it was showing the impact on the latent variable...  if I type

`mfx, eydx`

the outcome differ from the previous `mfx` - so, I am tending to believe that it was not a bug on the `mfx` command, but that `gllamm` was already yielding the marginal effects.  To check this, I tried to the `margins` command:

`margins, atmeans continuous`

this gives a completely different answer then the previous ones - and the command

`margins, atmeans dydx(independent_variables) continuous`

does not converge.  Does any one knows the answer to the following questions?

1. Is the `gllamm` already giving the marginal effects in the above case?
2. Am I using the `margins` command in the wrong way if I want to compute the marginal effects of each independent variable (they are all continuous)?  If so, what should I do instead?